# How to extract data from a List with property inside in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get the values of **symbol** and **position** from the list **x** below. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
class Contract:
    conId (int): The unique IB contract identifier.
    symbol (str): The contract (or its underlying) symbol.
    exchange (str): The destination exchange.
    currency (str): The underlying's currency.
    localSymbol (str): The contract's symbol
    tradingClass (str): The trading class name for this contract.

class Position(NamedTuple):
    account: str
    contract: Contract
    position: float
    avgCost: float

class ib_insync.objects.Position(account, contract, position, avgCost)

x = ib_insync.ib.IB.positions()
print(x)
```

Result:

```
Position(account='DU4204204', contract=Stock(conId=257944570, symbol='HLT', exchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='HLT', tradingClass='HLT'), position=20.0, avgCost=156.53), Position(account='DU4204204', contract=Stock(conId=5437, symbol='A', exchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='A', tradingClass='A'), position=13.0, avgCost=131)]
```

Target output:

```
HLT, 20.0 
A, 13
```

Comment: What do you know about the Position and Stock classes?

Comment: what is the ```Position``` in this list (the very first word after ```[```)??

Comment: Your `x` doesn't look like a proper list? What data structure is `x` suppose to be?

Comment: @Simon *x* is a viable list. What's missing are the declarations of the Stock and Position classes

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that runs with _only the code you have provided in your question_. Remember that SO users are not clairvoyant and cannot read the files on your computer to find the definitions of the `Position` and `Stock` classes. The answer to _"How can I access some information in an object of a class"_ depends very much on how that class is defined and what it does with the arguments passed to its constructor.

Comment: Just edited the question and the related classes are shown.

Comment: @Fireghost That is not pure Python code for a class definition. Also, what is *ib* ?

Comment: @LancelotduLac I am sorry that I am not good in the concept of class. I try my best to modify the question again. Thank you for your help!!
The official document of the class is get from here:
https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html#ib_insync.objects.Position

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that all constructor arguments are implemented as class properties. Therefore you should be able to access them with standard dot notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using the Interactive Brokers (IB) API. The documentation seems to suggest that all constructor arguments are available as class instance properties.

So, for the sake of discussion, let's emulate the Stock and Position classes like this:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.vars = kwargs
    @property
    def position(self):
        return self.vars.get('position')
    @property
    def contract(self):
        return self.vars.get('contract')
        
class Stock:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.vars = kwargs
    @property
    def symbol(self):
        return self.vars.get('symbol')
```

This is **not** how they're implemented in reality.

Now we have this list:

```
x = [Position(account='DU4204420', contract=Stock(conId=257944570, symbol='HLT', exchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='HLT', tradingClass='HLT'), position=20.0, avgCost=156.53), Position(account='DU4204420', contract=Stock(conId=5437, symbol='A', exchange='NYSE', currency='USD', localSymbol='A', tradingClass='A'), position=13.0, avgCost=131)]
```

Thus we can extract the relevant data as follows:

```
for position in x:
    print(position.contract.symbol, position.position)
```

Which gives this output:

```
HLT 20.0
A 13.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. 
That's what your said, it is able to access them with standard dot notation.